# When invoking latexmk with -silent, do the silent switches get appended to or completely replace the respective compile variable?

Tags: latexmk

In more detail, when invoking latexmk with `latexmk -silent -pdf`, do the silent switches (e.g. `$pdflatex_silent_switch`) get appended to the variable `$pdflatex` or completely replace the command specified in variable `$pdflatex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In commands like those specified by `$pdflatex` there is a "place-holder" `%O` for options. Any options that `latexmk` wants to use are substituted for `%O`.

For example, the default setting for `$pdflatex` is `pdflatex %O %S`.  At run time, `%S` is replaced by the name of the source file, and `%O` is replaced by the options.  E.g., when you invoke `latexmk` by `latexmk -silent -pdf main.tex`, the compilation is done by the command

```
pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder "main.tex"
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer and for developing such an amazing tool!